# How to Compare information schema column with Table Column in Sql Server2008 using inner Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a table called

`A` and it contains column called `A1` and it has `A21, A31 , A41` as row values

**A** :

```
   A1    
 +---+     
  A21    
  A31    
  A41
```

I have another table called `B`   and it has columns of `A21,A31,A41`

**B:**

```
 | A21 |  A31 | A41
```

Now how can i make a inner join to find column match ...whether same columns of B is same as A1 Row values....  (i.e)   Matching A1's Row values with B Column names

```
select A1
  from A a
  inner join information_schema.columns c on c.column_name = a.A
  where c.TABLE_NAME = 'B'
```

OutPut :

```
   A1
   A11
```

But I need

```
       A1    
      +---+     
       A21    
       A31    
       A41
```

Thanks in Advance

my query

```
 select Distinct c.Column_Name,Sorting_Order from Fee_Individual_New a 
 inner join information_schema.columns c on c.column_name = a.Column_Name 
 where c.TABLE_NAME ='Feed' and Delivered_to_mobile='Yes'
```

The output is coming in Ascending order .... I need the get the same structure as from table column values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but this might be what you mean:

```
select *
from A1 a
inner join information_schema.columns c on c.column_name = a.A1
where c.table_name = 'B'
```

Although why you want this is a bit of a mystery!

Comment: Less data? Edit your question to show what you expect given the data you've shown.

Comment: So you want all A1 values whether or not they match B column names? Why not just select A1 from a? Or do you want more information? If you do, put it in the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your help no its working fine.. problem is in our side

Comment: What does the query look like?

Comment: please see my updated question now i solved the ambiguous column error but values are coming in ascending order...i need to get the values by same structure from the table ... i dont want it in ascending or descending

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT
        A1.*
FROM
        A1
        INNER JOIN sys.columns S ON S.name = A1.name
        INNER JOIN sys.tables ST ON ST.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE
        ST.name = 'A2'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to match row values from table A to column names from table B,
maybe you should try something like this one:

```
SELECT B.B1, A.*
FROM
(SELECT B1
FROM B
UNPIVOT
(B FOR B1 IN ([A21], [A31], [A41])) AS UNPIVOTED) AS B
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT A1
FROM A) AS A
ON A.A1 = B.B1
```